# How can I generate in Python a matrix with n random elements between 1 and 30 and the rest of the elements equal to zeros?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, random

I have to generate a matrix with of shape 10^4 x 10^4 with 100 integer items randomly chosen 1 and 30 and the rest of the elements equals to 0. Can anybody help me? :pray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the matrix with zeros, and then add the random numbers, or create an empty matrix, add the random numbers, and fill the empty values with 0.

Comment: how can I can implement it?